# EntityAlreadyExists | Terraform AWS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am going to create resources using terraform. Here is my code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0aea56f3589631913"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "my-ec2-instance"
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name = "my-api"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "my-resource"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "example" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.example.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "example" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.example.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.example.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "HTTP"
  uri                     = "http://${aws_instance.example.private_ip}:8080"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  stage_name  = "prod"
}

output "api_gateway_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url
}
```

If I tried using `terraform apply` I am getting some errors such as,

> ╷ │ Error: creating IAM Role (ec2_role): EntityAlreadyExists: Role
> with name ec2_role already exists. │       status code: 409, request
> id: 3b94076c-9969-4701-a295-cf0de3f1aac9 │  │   with
> aws_iam_role.ec2_role, │   on terraform.tf line 34, in resource
> "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role": │   34: resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role"
> { │  ╵

How can I remove this EntityAlreadyExists issue, Like if the already exists ignore that line and go to other.

Answer (score 1):

If that iam role is always sure to exist in the targeted environment, then you can simply capture it using the `data{}` block. Your code does not seem to match the output, so the error must be pointing to another .tf file in your solution. Search the solution for something like:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role"{
...
}
```

then, replace it with

```
data "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role"{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Like if the already exists ignore that line and go to other.

Terraform does not work this way. If you define a resource, then Terraform will always try to create that resource, and if it already exists you will always get an error. You can't tell Terraform to check if something exists, and skip it if it does.

You an use `terraform import` to tell Terraform to take control of the existing resource, instead of trying to create a new resource.

Alternatively, you can define a datasource instead of a resource, if you know that the resource already exists and you don't want Terraform to manage the existing resource.